# Biblatex undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@ARTICLE
    {GBGP,
    author  = {Ghisu, Tiziano, Bachisio Arca, Grazia Pellizzaro, and Pierpaolo Duce.},
    title   = {An Improved Cellular Automata for Wildfire Spread},
    year    = {2015},
    journal = {Procedia Computer Science},
    volume  = {51},
    pages   = {2287-2296}
}
@ARTICLE
    {JAMM,
    author  = {Jellouli, O., A. Bernoussi, M. {MÃ¢atouk}, and M. Amharref.},
    title   = {Forest fire modelling using cellular automata: application to the watershed Oued Laou (Morocco)},
    year    = {2016},
    journal = {Mathematical and Computer Modelling of Dynamical Systems},
    volume  = {22},
    number  = {5},
    pages   = {493-507}
}
@ARTICLE
    {XLLQ,
    author  = {Xuehua, Wang, Liu Chang, Liu Jiaqi, Qin Xuezhi, Wang Ning, and Zhou Wenjun.},
    title   = {A cellular automata model for forest fire spreading simulation},
    year    = {2016},
    journal = {2016 IEEE Symposium Series on Computational Intelligence (SSCI)}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
```

This is currently my bib file but when I try to use **\parentcite** it gives an undefined control sequence. I'm guessing my bib file is wrong in someway but I can't see where. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `\parencite`, not `\parentcite`. ("paren" for "parenthesis")

Comment: It's `\parencite`, not `\parentcite`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. just a note "parent" could stand for "parenthesis" too :P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error is due to a typo: `\parentcite` instead of `\parencite`.

Comment: @Moriambar Not really, "paren" is a common abbreviation (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paren#English), while "parent" is a mother/father.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know I was kidding

Comment: Well that was a silly mistake to make thanks